# Spring Rest JSON conversion

Tags: java, angularjs, json, spring, rest

I am working on Spring Rest and Angularjs. I have a problem on how the objects are being converted. Lets say I have two classes.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "fooId", scope = Foo.class)
class Foo {
   int fooId;
   String fooName;
   String fooTitle;
   Bar bar;
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "barId", scope = Bar.class)
class Bar {
   int barId;
   String barName;
   String barTitle;
   int fooId;
}
```

When I send the Foo object with Bar to Angularjs, I am getting something like this:

```
{
  "fooId": 1,
  "fooName": "foo-name",
  "fooTitle": "foo-title",
  "bar": 1
}
```

I was expecting to get like this:

```
{
  "fooId": 11,
  "fooName": "foo-name",
  "fooTitle": "foo-title",
  "bar":  {
      "barId": 22,
      "barName": "bar-name",
      "barTitle": "bar-title",
      "fooId": 11
  }
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Could not produce the result you get with `spring 4.2.1.RELEASE` and `jackson-databind 2.4.4`. I'm getting the expected results. Used Chrome Rest Client to test

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove @JsonIdentityInfo annotation from your Bar class - default rest controller convert classes well without it!